# Mongodb query add field after doing a search on another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following models:

Team:

```js
const teamSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    trim: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    trim: true
  }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

Member:

```js
const memberSchema = new Schema({
  id_team: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Team',
    required: true
  },
  id_user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: roles,
    default: 'user'
  }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

ControllerTeam:

```js
export const index = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) =>
  Team.count(query)
    .then(count => Team.find(query, select, cursor)
      .populate('owner', ['name', 'surname', 'role'])
      .then((teams) => ({
        count,
        rows: teams.map((team) => team.view())
      }))
    )
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(next)
```

I want to know if a specific user that is passed to the query with the name of `id_user`,
if he is part of that group, also returning the role within it in case.

Also knowing the number of members within it.

But I'm having doubts about how to do it, I have to use `aggregate`.

Can you give me a hand?